# Node.js: Returning proper JSON from mongoose query

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I  have this express application with mongoDB as the database and handlebars as my server-side templating engine. I am not using AngularJS or Ajax in my application.

In one of the routes, I have to render the page as well as send over a json file from the database. However, I am not able to achieve this.

Here is code snippet the  my route:

```
router.get('/disks', function(req, res, next) {
  places.find({"category": "disks"}, function(err, disks){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }

       res.render('disks', 
        { 
          'risime': JSON.stringify(disks)
        });
      console.log(disks); // PROPERLY LOGS TO THE CONSOLE
  });
});
```

In the hbs, I am trying to capture it, but I don't even think that it is JSON.

Here is how it gets logged in the client side:

```
[{&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;5704630a7d4cd367f8dsdce7&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Seagate&quot;,:&quot;This awesome Hard disk&quot;,&quot;,&quot;categories&quot;:[&quot;SDD&quot;,&quot;256GB&quot;]}]
```

What is the issue and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's handlebars that "html escapes" your string (which is what you normally want).

if you don't want that, you can use the "triple-stash" notation, like this:

```
{{{risime}}}
```

You can read about this here: http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping

Comment: Um, what are the disadvantages of ignoring the HTML escape characters?

Comment: Security. If the string comes from an untrusted source (eg. user input), the string could be unsafe and without any escaping it could easily contain html tags (like `<script>`). That could be use to attack the website with, for example, an XSS exploit.

Comment: Oh, okay. But this string is coming from the database, so no issues if I escape the HTML right?

Comment: it depends on how the string gets into the database ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this before render:

```
res.type('application/json');
```

The client will know this is a JSON, not a HTML or a plain text and it will be shown correctly.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Um, but I am also using res.render() Won't this be affected?

Comment: I tried it out, this does not work with res.render(). It just displays my page as plain-text instead of a web page.